# Android: ViewGroup in custom Toast

Tags: android

I created a custom `Toast` in my app and I have put in a class to call it from anywhere. It needs a `ViewGroup` in the `findViewById`. But I don't know send it when I'm in a class that extends `Activity` and is not an event ... thanks

**Module.java**

```
public static void toast(Context context, View view, String texto, int perfilColor, int icono) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
    View layouttoast = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast, (ViewGroup)view.findViewById(R.id.toastcustom));
    ((TextView) layouttoast.findViewById(R.id.texttoast)).setText(Html.fromHtml(texto));

    ((ImageView) layouttoast.findViewById(R.id.imagenToast)).setImageResource(icono);
    ((LinearLayout) layouttoast.findViewById(R.id.toastcustom)).setBackgroundResource(cargarColorToast(perfilColor));

    Toast mytoast = new Toast(context);
    mytoast.setView(layouttoast);
    mytoast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    mytoast.show();
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
...

if(...) {
    Module.toast(MainActivity.this, ¿? , "error", color, icon);
}
```

Comment: Please add an actual question and explain where your errors appear.

Comment: I have not errors. My problem is the parameter View view. I don't know  that send when the call to toast is not inside of an onclick...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i use a custom toast.

```
public class CustomToast {

    public static Toast makeToast(Activity activity, String text, int duraion ){
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_achievement, (ViewGroup) activity.findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));

        TextView textView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
        textView.setText(text);

        Toast toast = new Toast(activity.getApplicationContext());
        toast.setDuration(duraion);
        toast.setView(layout);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        return toast;
    }
}
```

and the xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toast_layout_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:padding="8dp" >

 <!-- content goes here-->

</LinearLayout>
```

not that the id has to be toast_layout_root or it wont work.

Basically, you don't need to pass a view along anyway.

Comment: What send you how activity?

Comment: a toast needs a context, usually you are creating it from an activity/fragment, in both cases you can pass the activity as context. from within activity, pass 'this'. from fragment pass getActivity()